# Is there any one website which contains many good C# screencasts?

Tags: c#

Is there any one website which contains many good C# screencasts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I like the [channel 9 screencasts](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/CSharp/) tagged C#..

Answer (score 6):

[Dimecasts.net](http://dimecasts.net/) is coming out with lots of good, short screencasts on various .NET topics.  Some in the ALT.NET space.  Most of the example code they write is in C#.

Answer (score 4):

dnrTV

> dnrTv is a fusion of a training video
>   and an interview show. Training videos
>   are typically sterile and one-way.
>   Let's face it, you can only take so
>   much. But you need to see the code! In
>   this format, you get the spontaneity
>   of an interview talk show, and the
>   detail of a webcast or training video.
>
> Carl Franklin is the host of the
>   wildly popular mp3 talk show .NET
>   Rocks!, which he started recording in
>   August, 2002. dnrTV launched on
>   January 12th, 2006, the same week as
>   .NET Rocks! show number 159!
>
> We see dnrTV as a natural adjunct to
>   .NET Rocks!, allowing more technical
>   topics to be explored in detail. As
>   always, Carl keeps the atmosphere
>   light and conversational, which makes
>   for a nice way to spend your lunch
>   hour!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the delay but I think the [TekPub](http://www.tekpub.com/) Screencast is just great.

Answer (score 2):

- [WindowsClient.net WPF Videos](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx)
- [Visual C# Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336819.aspx)
- [YouTube search for 'C# programming'](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=c%23+programming&search_type=&aq=f)

Answer (score 2):

You should checkout [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight-training.net).  They have fantastic training videos and their C# Fundamentals video is their most popular.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.asp.net/learn/

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net

Answer (score 1):

Ok...these are not about C# as such, but if you fancy learning about NHibernate, the [Summer of NHibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) vids are probably the best I've ever watched. Decent sized captures and even though they're about NHibernate I learned a thing or two about refactoring unit tests as well. I even donated because I thought they were that good. 10/10

Answer (score 1):

**Learn C# on YouTube**: [**89 C# tutorials collection**](http://www.youtube.com/view%5Fplay%5Flist?p=CF53106B24EF9ACB). Mainly examples of how to do something with C#. [**Another big collection of 98 C# videos**](http://www.youtube.com/view%5Fplay%5Flist?p=13141D4688033C31). It covers a lot of C# fundamentals.