# Video courses for C#

Tags: c#, .net

#### Duplicate

> - [Is there any one website which contains many good C# screencasts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155393/is-there-any-one-website-which-contains-many-good-c-screencasts)
> - [C# Training videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100772/c-training-videos)

---

So can anyone recommend a set of videos for learning C# preferably free ( in my experience the nonfree videos seem to lean moe towards shlock ),

I understand that some universities are now using C# as their "101" language.
Does any such university have videos in an open coursework series?

PS: I am particularly interested in university courses. These are the ones most likely to have a long term ( 3-4 months ) structured approach aka a syllabus.

Comment: Apparently "merchandise that is shoddy or inferior": http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shlock

Comment: Shlock? ( I am going to so piss off the ... ehmm ... fools in this forum. )

Anything written by Herb Schildt or Jesse Liberty.
Almost everything with "for Dummies" in the title. ( There are a few good ones. )
Everything with " in X days " or " in X hours " in it.
Everything with "Unleashed" in the title.
Etc.
Get the idea?

Comment: BubbaT: Oh, shlock == crap. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think Plural Sight has the best courses. they have a Free C# intro.

http://www.pluralsight.com/main/olt/Course.aspx?n=dotnet-csharp-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

They aren't free, but every video I've seen from [LearnVisualStudio.Net](http://www.learnvisualstudio.net) has been pretty good.  I got a 'lifetime' membership for $90 and it's been well worth it.

Comment: +1 I have had a lifetime membership with LearnVisualStudio.net since late 2004 and never regretted it. I find some of the videos rather bland and trivial but overall it is a great learning resource.

Answer (score 1):

[**Learn C# on YouTube**](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=CF53106B24EF9ACB): 89 C# tutorials collection. Mainly examples of how to do something with C#. Another [**big collection of 98 C# videos**](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=13141D4688033C31). It covers a lot of C# fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

I find [AppDev](http://www.appdev.com/) good. There is a lot of free stuff there (although not all).

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a good amount of learning videos. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336766.aspx).
The videos usually target a specific subjects and have enough details for you to learn a lot from them.

Also, Microsoft makes videos for ASP.NET if you're looking to do web-based apps. Have a look [here](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/videos/)

Comment: Thanks. THey are on my list, but I am looking for something more structured.

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft Learning Manager - 
http://learning.microsoft.com/Manager/Catalog.aspx?view=free

You pay for most of the videos but there are some free introductory ones as well that are good.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

- these are videos by Learnvisualstudio.net provided freely by microsoft : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308734.aspx)
- C# soup to nuts webcasts by William J. Steele : [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/wsteele/archive/2007/01/29/c-soup-to-nuts-webcast-links.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://polishwords.com.pl/video_tutorials.php?g=programowanie_w_visual_studio But unfortunately in Polish Language :)