# Screencast material for C#

Tags: c#

I am looking for some really informative screencasts for C# which would serve a good starting point for a beginner.

Any ideas or pointers. 
(something similar to Dave Thomas for Ruby and Ryan Bates for Rails).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good resources here:

[Is there any one website which contains many good C# screencasts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155393/is-there-any-one-website-which-contains-many-good-c-screencasts)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers "[How Do I?" Videos for Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vcsharp/bb798022.aspx)" On this page you will find dozens of videos designed for all Visual C# developers, from the novice to the professional.